# How to increase point density in julia plots?

Tags: plot, julia

I'm plotting the function `tan` but it's not rendered cleanly because the point density is too low around Inf values.

```
using Plots
plot(x -> tan(x), 1, 10)
```

[tan function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyJLd.png)

How can I increase point density ? I don't see it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I found the syntax :
`plot(x -> tan(x), 1:0.0001:10, ylims=(-20, 20))`
with this the x axis goes from 1 to 10 with a step of 0.0001

Comment: As an aside, the `x -> tan(x)` is redundant, you can just say `tan`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just to explicitly specify a vector of `x` points:

```
using Plots
x = 0:0.001:10
plot(x, tan.(x), xlims=(0,10), ylims=(-1000,1000))
```

[image: tan(x) from 0 to 10]